# Postgres: Generating table of customer events (1 for purchase, 0 for null)

Tags: r, database, postgresql, prediction

I am seeking to prep a CSV file from our postgres database and import to R to do some machine learning/inference analysis.

**Goal**: To have a table that has a record for each customer (unique ID) and each date (e.g., 2017-11-10) and a 1 for a purchase event and 0 for no purchase event.

I started off with generate_series:

```
SELECT 
  date(dd) as date,
  c.id,
  CASE WHEN pt.customer_id is not null then 1 else 0 end as customer_made_purchase
FROM generate_series ('2017-10-01'::date, '2017-12-01'::date, '1 day'::interval) dd
LEFT JOIN purchase_table as pt on date(dd) = date(pt.purchased_at)
LEFT JOIN customer_table as c on c.id = pt.customer_id
```

However, the table produced has rows only for purchase events (It doesn't include customers who did not have a purchase event). Thinking about it, it makes sense since it will only generate records for customers that are in the purchase_table. So, how can I generate table that has a row for each customer on each date? I know that will be a VERY large table but I'm trying to predict customer purchases. Open to other ideas as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution might be a cross join (aka Cartesian product) on date and your user list. You'll probably want to follow up by joining in the user create date and filtering records prior to that date.